# How to access the BigQuery Web UI without a navigation error

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems as of this morning I cannot access the BigQuery Web UI. The Web UI reports an error when I try to navigate there from Cloud Console.

[The error as it appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJCKJ.png)

The URL that results looks like this:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/navigation-error;errorUrl=%2Fbigquery%3Fproject%3DPROJECTNAME?project=PROJECTNAME
```

Any ideas on how to get around this so I can access the Web UI and continue with my analyses? I tried to navigate to existing query links but there the page is just blank.
The Web Inspector reports quite a few errors. The top one is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
for URL https://cloudusersettings-pa.clients6.google.com/v1alpha1/settings/CONSOLE_NAV_HIDE_PRODUCTS?key=SOME_KEY_HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like this has been officially acknowledged as an incident by GCP](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/20008), so I will just have to wait for a resolution and blast my queries off using the API.

Comment: fyi: seems to be working again, i'm getting access to the bq console again